# Firebase serve and deploy not running new version of Vue Project

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

When running `firebase serve` or `firebase deploy --only hosting` it was showing my old project. However, now it shows me the "Welcome to Firebase Hosting" screen

[image: Welcome screen.]

Here's what I've tried doing:

1. Uninstalling and installing firebase again.
2. Restarting the firebase project (`firebase init`).
3. `Npm run build`
4. Deleting the dist folder.
5. Made sure to set firebase to read the dist folder.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

**Note: The project runs as expected with `npm run serve` . I'm  running JavaScript, not TypeScript.**

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed by recovering some deleted firebase files such as firebase.json and .firebaserc